# Log specific property value from object

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

`choices: {'Frederico' : true, 'Roberto' : false, 'Carlos' : false}`

and I am trying to log only the property that has a true value

```
for(var keyProperty in choices) {
    if(choices.hasOwnProperty(keyProperty)) {
      console.log(choices[keyProperty]);
    }
}
```

But I am getting all properly values logged. How I can log the property keys that has the `true` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for true:

```
for(var keyProperty in choices) {
    if(choices.hasOwnProperty(keyProperty) && choices[keyProperty] === true) {
      console.log(choices[keyProperty]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be even more refactored to just 
 `if (choices[keyProperty])`

Comment: That wouldn't ignore the truthy values @finalfreq

Comment: I didn't copied and I was 'defending' you. My comment was a response to finalfreq as the @ shows :)

Comment: Thank you baao and taguenizy, that worked. I sticked with you refactored option.

Answer (score 1):

`for(var keyProperty in choices) {
    if(allChoices.hasOwnProperty(keyProperty) && choices[keyProperty] === true) {
      console.log(keyProperty);
    }
}`

This way you get logged the property that has a `true` value and ignore the truthy values also.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check if the type of the object is `boolean`. Otherwise all truthy values will be logged.

```
var choice = choices[keyProperty];
if(allChoices.hasOwnProperty(keyProperty) && typeof(choice) === 'boolean' && choice) {

}
```